# Why is my python dictionary updating when it is not supposed to (conditions are not being met)?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to update a dictionary with data I am obtaining from sorting methods. I am obtaining the time it takes for a certain algorithm to finish, I am also counting how many swaps and how many comparisons the algorithm is making. After my sorting function returns the values I want to update a dictionary and I am doing this using a bunch of nested loops.

This dictionary that I want to update is a dictionary that contains nested lists and other dictionaries. This is what my dictionary looks like:

```
time_and_data_dictionary={"Time":12,"Data Comparisons":12,"Data Swaps":12}
selection_sort_information={"selection sort":time_and_data_dictionary}
bubble_sort_information={"bubble sort":time_and_data_dictionary}
insertion_sort_information={"insertion sort":time_and_data_dictionary}
array_of_sorting_algorithms=[selection_sort_information,bubble_sort_information,insertion_sort_information]
dictionary={"Ascending_Sorted_250":array_of_sorting_algorithms,"Ascending_Sorted_500":array_of_sorting_algorithms,"Ascending_Sorted_1000": array_of_sorting_algorithms,"Ascending_Sorted_10000":array_of_sorting_algorithms,"Descending_Sorted_250":array_of_sorting_algorithms,"Descending_Sorted_500":array_of_sorting_algorithms," Descending_Sorted_1000": array_of_sorting_algorithms,"Descending_Sorted_10000":array_of_sorting_algorithms,"Random_Sorted_250":array_of_sorting_algorithms,"Random_Sorted_500":array_of_sorting_algorithms," Random_Sorted_1000":array_of_sorting_algorithms,"Random_Sorted_10000":array_of_sorting_algorithms}
```

The calls to the functions looks something like this:

```
start = time()
tuple_selection_sort_rd250 = selection_sort_array(unordered_data_250)
end=time()
td_selection_sort_rd250=end-start
start = time()
tuple_bubble_sort_rd250 = bubble_sort_array(unordered_data_250)
end=time()
td_bubble_sort_rd250=end-start
tuple_insertion_sort_rd250 = insertion_sort_array(unordered_data_250)
end=time()
td_insertion_sort_rd250=end-start
```

And the dictionary update procedure looks something like this:

```
print(dictionary,"beginning")
for i,j in dictionary.items():
    for x,val in enumerate(j):
        for k,v in val.items():
            for y,z in v.items():


                if i=="Random_Sorted_250":
                    if x==0 :
                        if y==t:
                            dictionary[i][x][k][y]=td_selection_sort_rd250
                        if y==dc:
                            dictionary[i][x][k][y]=tuple_selection_sort_rd250[0]
                            
                        if y==ds:
                            dictionary[i][x][k][y]=tuple_selection_sort_rd250[1]
                           
                    if x==1 :
                            print("is",k,x)
                            print(i, x, k, t, dc, ds, type(i), type(x), type(k), type(t), type(dc), type(ds))
                            if y==t:
                                dictionary[i][x][k][y] = td_bubble_sort_rd250
                             
                            if y==dc:
                                dictionary[i][x][k][y] = tuple_bubble_sort_rd250[0]

                            if y==ds:
                                dictionary[i][x][k][y] = tuple_bubble_sort_rd250[1]

                    if x==2 :
                        print("going",k,x)
                        print(i, x, k, t, dc, ds, type(i), type(x), type(k), type(t), type(dc), type(ds))

                        if y==t:
                            dictionary[i][x][k][y] = td_insertion_sort_rd250
                        if y==dc:
                            dictionary[i][x][k][y] = tuple_insertion_sort_rd250[0]
                        if y==ds:
                            dictionary[i][x][k][y] = tuple_insertion_sort_rd250[1]

                    print(dictionary, x)
print(dictionary,"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
print(len(list(dictionary)),"count")
```

My output is showing me the same value for all my sorting algorithms i.e., the selection sort, the bubble sort and the insertion sort. When debugging I can see that all the values are the same across the different keys i.e., all the times are the same including the ones that I haven't including in my if conditions. Is there something I am missing regarding dictionaries and how updating them works? Is it my for loops and the fact that I am using `.values()` method?

The output looks something like:

```
{'Ascending_Sorted_250': [{'selection sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'bubble sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'insertion sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}], 'Ascending_Sorted_500': [{'selection sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'bubble sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'insertion sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}], 'Ascending_Sorted_1000': [{'selection sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'bubble sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'insertion sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}], 'Ascending_Sorted_10000': [{'selection sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'bubble sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'insertion sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}], 'Descending_Sorted_250': [{'selection sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'bubble sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'insertion sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}], 'Descending_Sorted_500': [{'selection sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'bubble sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'insertion sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}], 'Descending_Sorted_1000': [{'selection sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'bubble sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'insertion sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}], 'Descending_Sorted_10000': [{'selection sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'bubble sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'insertion sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}], 'Random_Sorted_250': [{'selection sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'bubble sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'insertion sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}], 'Random_Sorted_500': [{'selection sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'bubble sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'insertion sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}], 'Random_Sorted_1000': [{'selection sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'bubble sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'insertion sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}], 'Random_Sorted_10000': [{'selection sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'bubble sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}, {'insertion sort': {'Time': 0.015619993209838867, 'Data Comparisons': 0, 'Data Swaps': 0}}]} $$$$$$$$$$$$$$
12 count
```

Someone please explain. Please ignore the in-line debugging statements.

Comment: All the `xxx_sort_information` dictionaries contain references to the same `time_and_data_dictionary`. So if you update one of them, you update them all. Make a copy of the dictionary.

Comment: This is correct and I was guessing that might be the case. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: So I changed it by assigning the `{"Time":12,"Data Comparisons":12,"Data Swaps":12}` to each of the `xxx_sort_information` dictionaries but it still is updating dictionaries that are not in my condition.

Comment: You can use `time_and_data_dictionary.copy()`

Comment: All those 1-letter variables have my head spinning, I can't keep track of what is what.

Comment: You have the same problem with `array_of_sorting_information` when you put it into `dictionary`. Use `.copy()` there as well.

Comment: Yes, I realized that `.copy()` might be the better way to go. Thank you again.

Comment: I did `.copy` to virtually every dictionary/list assignment but it seems that some of the earlier things (like `Ascending_Sorted_250` and` Descending_Sorted_250`   are still getting updated even though they are not placed in the if conditions for it.

Comment: Do the sorting functions return a new list or do they modify the original list in place?

Comment: They don't return a new list they modify the original in place but honestly that has nothing to do with my assignment in the dictionary. Although, I will fix that.

Comment: Of course it does. It means that all the `XXX_sort_rd250` variables contain the same list! So when you assign `dictionary[i][x][k][y] = XXX_sort_rd250` you're putting the same list in every dictionary element.

Comment: Yes, I do realize that, but as of now the problem is not that `dictionary[i][x][k][y] = XXX_sort_rd250` it is the fact that things like `Ascending_Sorted_250`, `Descending_Sorted_250`, `Ascending_Sorted_500`, `Descending_Sorted_500` are changing even though I haven't put them as conditions in the for loop. I have also changed the sorting algorithms to instead use a copy.

Comment: I may not have noticed all the places where you're sharing lists/dictionaries. But any time you see multiple items being changed together, that's the reason. Python doesn't duplicate data by itself.

Comment: BTW, you might want to use the `timeit` module.

Comment: Ok, thank you I haven't used it before but I will look into it. Is `timeit` a better option than just `time()`

Comment: It automates the things you do when timing code, like getting the start and end time and subtracting them. It can optionally run the code multiple times and calculate the average.

Comment: Honestly, I have shown all the list and dictionary sharing there is not much more but I will update my question above to the better version that includes the copy statement

Comment: You probably should have the test `if i=="Random_Sorted_250":` in the `for i, j in dictionary.items()` loop, not nested into the inner loop.

Comment: Use `copy.deepcopy()` instead of just `list.copy()` and `dict.copy()`. You're not copying the nested lists.

Comment: I just used `copy.deepcopy()` and it looks like it fixed it. Thank you so much for your help. I will look into the `timeit` module.